# SearchView.setSearchableInfo cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: android, android-studio

I am following along a YouTube Tutorial on how to get a query from a searchview and I am getting this error cannot be referenced from a static context.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.zoggfrombetelgeuse.clef;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar my_toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(my_toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.my_toolbar_tile);

    Intent searchIntent = getIntent();
    if(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(searchIntent.getAction())){

        String query = searchIntent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);

    SearchView searchview = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchManager searchmanager = (SearchManager)       getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchmanager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName())  );

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

MainActicity is my only Activity.

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.zoggfrombetelgeuse.clef">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".MainActivity"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"
            />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I know it's not an answer, but if you like to have a searchview that looks like the one in material design guidelines, take a look at this one: https://github.com/Mauker1/MaterialSearchView

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
SearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchmanager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName())  );
```

to

```
searchview.setSearchableInfo(searchmanager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName())  );
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new too java and it is very confusing to keep track of class, variables, methods and what not. This is so complex.

Comment: Hi, I ran the code and I am getting the following error in the logcat

 android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.SearchView